# Why is Deja-Dup slow to backup to Ubuntu One location?

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, deja-dup

I am using Deja-Dup to backup my home directory to Ubuntu One.  Doing a full backup seems to take at least a day.

My broadband upload speed is measuring about 3Mb/s at the moment, but when I use system monitor and look at the network traffic whilst Deja-Dup is running, it seems to only be uploading about 20Kb/s.  This is making the backup unsuable.

Any ideas why it's not using more network bandwidth?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, but had the same problem in 11.10.  Backing up to a network drive on the local network is fine, so it seems that uploading to Ubuntu One is slow?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Its quite possible it is a bug in Ubuntu One and the issue is not with Deja-Dup  See this bug report for more information  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/990718

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. Could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!